# Loop through liquid advanced custom field to return multiple metafield values

Tags: for-loop, shopify, liquid

I've built the following liquid `for` loop to retrieve & output data from a repeating advanced custom field in Shopify. The ACF namespace is `faq`, and contains `heading` and `content` data. My current loop is as follows:

```
<div class="feed-faqs">

    {% if page.metafields.faq != blank %}

        {% assign faqs = page.metafields.faq %}

        {% for item in faqs %}

            {% assign i = forloop.index %}
            
            <div class="item item--{{ i }}">
                {{ heading[i] }}
                {{ content[i] }}
            </div>
            
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

</div>
```

However, on the frontend, this loop returns the following:

```
<div class="feed-faqs">
    <div class="item item--1">            
    </div>            
    <div class="item item--2">            
    </div>
</div>
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve (to output multiple values from a repeating ACF field) possible with this approach, and if so, where have I gone wrong in fetching the `header` & `content` data?

Comment: You need to post the data format sample here which is store into FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, so leaving this answer for anyone else in the future:

```
<div class="feed--faqs">

    {% if page.metafields.faq != blank %}

        {% assign faqs = page.metafields.faq.heading %}

        {% for value in faqs %}

            {% assign i = forloop.index0 %}
            
            <div class="item item--{{ i }}">
                <h4>{{ page.metafields.faq.heading[i] }}</h4>
                <p>{{ page.metafields.faq.content[i] }}</p>
            </div>
            
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

</div>
```

Metafield value type is set to 'Json String'.

For reference, I'm using the ArenaCommerce Advanceds Custom Fields app: https://apps.shopify.com/advanced-custom-field.